# I am using Yosemite - but my Mail is v 8 - how can I upgrade Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I want to use an auto configure for my new email address - but it says it can't do it automatically because my email program isn't a v10+.  What is the problem - is there a Mail upgrade??

Comment: As far as I knowm v 8 is the only one available for Yosemite.

Comment: OS X Yosemite comes with Mail version 8. Can you please post the exact steps you're taking, including the exact names of buttons you click or fields you enter (feel free to omit your actual username and email address). Then please provide the verbatim error message.

Comment: My auto configure says it needs to be running v10 or greater... so that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no higher version than 8 for Apple's Mail app.

Maybe is your auto configure talking about Microsoft Outlook version which is higher than 10.